# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=12;AT YEAR YEARS MONTH MONTHS DAY DAYS HOUR HOURS MINUTE MINUTE

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am trying to delete one of row using jdbc statement of my DB2 table but I am getting below Exception

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
> SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=12;AT YEAR YEARS MONTH MONTHS
> DAY DAYS HOUR HOURS MINUTE MINUTE

query is as follows

```
DELETE FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE ((PID_FROM = 'ABC123' AND PID = 'DEF456 ') OR (DEPT_FROM = '' AND DEPT_TO = ''))  AND  ST_FROM = '2022-07-28 12:44:37.464629428' AND ST_TO = '2022-07-28 12:44:37.464629428'
```

Dataype of ST_FROM and ST_TO  is Timestamp in DB2 table.

Comment: The timestamp literals need to be single-quoted (unless the real query uses parameter markers), and they need to follow the correct format for the Db2-server platform. To see that format use either `values current timestamp` (for Db2-LUW) or `select current timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy1` (other platforms) and use that as example, and you can also use `TIMESTAMP(....)` around the literals.

Comment: do I have to use TO_TIMESTAMP() function?

Comment: Both functions `TIMESTAMP()` and `TO_TIMESTAMP()` return a timestamp. Use whichever one meets your functional requirements.

Comment: What if use java.sql.Timestamp.ValueOf()

Answer (score 0):

The question is about data type conversion: string (`S` column of this virtual table `T`) to timestamp.
String constant must be enclosed in single quotes.
If you have a string representation of timestamp as in the example, you may use expressions as for TS1 and TS2 without the format specification,  and all 3 expressions return the same.

```
SELECT 
  S::TIMESTAMP                                  AS TS1  -- since V 11.1
, TIMESTAMP (S)                                 AS TS2
, TO_TIMESTAMP (S, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9') AS TS3
FROM
(
  VALUES '2022-07-28 12:44:37.464629428'
) T (S)
```